# .NET C# Enum Json deserialize with a dash in the EnumMember value without newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

I am using `System.Text.Json.Serialization` I am trying to deserialize a member with a dash in the `EnumMember` value `CheckStatus`.

```
  [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter))]
  public enum CheckStatus
  {
       [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = "newFile")]
       NewFile,

       [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = "check-status")]
       CheckStatus,
  }
```

I have written a `BindModelAsync`

```
   public class FileStatusModelBuilder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {

            var rawData = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).FirstValue;
            rawData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(rawData);
            CheckStatus result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CheckStatus>(rawData);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

When passing in `newFile` the binding works and will bind to `NewFile`, but as soon as I use `check-status` I get the following error.

```
The JSON value could not be converted to [...].CheckStatus. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 15.
```

I don't want to use `newtonsoft` but would like to be able to have an enum with a dash in the `EnumMember` value.

Comment: Why are yo telling us what you're not using? Why aren't you telling us what you are using? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Text.Json` still seems to not support `System.Runtime.Serialization` (and it seems it will not be, based on [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29975)), so you can implement custom serializer, for example this workaround from this [github issue on the topic](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31081#issuecomment-907153303):

```cs
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverterEx<CheckStatus>))]
public enum CheckStatus
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "newFile")]
    NewFile,

    [EnumMember(Value = "check-status")]
    CheckStatus,
}

public class JsonStringEnumConverterEx<TEnum> : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<TEnum>
    where TEnum : struct, System.Enum
{

    private readonly Dictionary<TEnum, string> _enumToString = new();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, TEnum> _stringToEnum = new();
    private readonly Dictionary<int, TEnum> _numberToEnum = new();

    public JsonStringEnumConverterEx()
    {
        var type = typeof(TEnum);

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues<TEnum>())
        {
            var enumMember = type.GetMember(value.ToString())[0];
            var attr = enumMember.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false)
                .Cast<EnumMemberAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

            _stringToEnum.Add(value.ToString(), value);
            var num = Convert.ToInt32(type.GetField("value__")
                .GetValue(value));
            if (attr?.Value != null)
            {
                _enumToString.Add(value, attr.Value);
                _stringToEnum.Add(attr.Value, value);
                _numberToEnum.Add(num, value);
            }
            else
            {
                _enumToString.Add(value, value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public override TEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var type = reader.TokenType;
        if (type == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            var stringValue = reader.GetString();
            if (_stringToEnum.TryGetValue(stringValue, out var enumValue))
            {
                return enumValue;
            }
        }
        else if (type == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            var numValue = reader.GetInt32();
            _numberToEnum.TryGetValue(numValue, out var enumValue);
            return enumValue;
        }

        return default;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(_enumToString[value]);
    }
}
```